# Using glut to prevent the mouse from leaving the window

Tags: c++, glut

I'm using glut for a game right now and I'm trying to keep the mouse inside the window. This isn't a first person shooter so locking it in the center is no good. I already know about `glutWarpPointer(int, int);` and I've trying things that work (kinda).

I've tried having the mouse warp back to the nearest edge of the window when it leaves, this works, but for a split second you see the mouse outside of the window and teleport back in. I don't want that, I want it to seem like the mouse just hits the edge of the window and stops going any further in that direction, while keeping movement in any other available direction. Like you would expect it to work.

Comment: @KillianDS, it's not a duplicate as the solution to the other one is to warp to the middle of the screen. This is not an FPS though and you can't do that.

Comment: @KillianDS No, that is for an fps game, so they want to lock the mouse in the center, I want to hold the mouse in the window and prevent it from leaving.

Comment: This is too hostile to the user.  Run it full screen if this is important.

Comment: How/when did you check whether the pointer left your window?

Comment: @HansPassant, haha yeah I can imagine the users shouting "give me my mouse back you #@$ @#!$ !#@$"

Comment: @K.G. I used glutEntryFunc() and tested for GLUT_LEFT.

Comment: @Hans Passant Maybe, but I don't think so, the mouse will unlock when you pause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not exactly an answer to your question, but it is an answer to your problem!

Almost every game has its own cursors. They would hide the mouse, and draw the cursor manually where the mouse should be positioned.

If you get your own cursor image and do as I said, you can simply draw the curser at the edge of the screen, even though the mouse position reads out of boundaries. Then you can warp the mouse back in.

Comment: I haven't tried adding my own cursor yet (or ever actually), so I'm wondering, will the real mouse show up for a brief second when it leaves the window even though the custom cursor, if so, how can I solve that?

Other than that, this is probably what I'll be doing, thank you, I'll accept as soon as the timer is up :).

Comment: I actually don't know. Like the comments in your question, trapping the mouse in a windowed application is a bit scary to the users, but I believe if you hide the mouse with GLUT, it would stay hidden if it goes out of the window (which is even more scary) (just don't forget to unhide it) Anyway, best answer is to add a hide/show to your program see what happens.

Comment: Side note, check [SDL](www.libsdl.org/) out if you had time. It's much better than GLUT in my opinion.

Comment: Ah, yes, I DO like SDL, but I'm trying something new this time. There's things about SDL I like and things about glut I like. So I like to switch between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Tried to search and figure this out and couldn't find an answer, so I implemented it myself. Here is what worked for my first person camera case:

callback from `glutPassiveMotion`

**CODE SAMPLE**

```
void Game::passiveMouseMotion(int x, int y)
{

    //of my code for doing the cam, yours is may be different, this is based on the example from https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera
    if (firstMouse) {
    lastX = x;
    lastY = y;
    firstMouse = false;
    }

    float xoffset = x - lastX;
    float yoffset = lastY - y; // reversed since y-coordinates go from bottom to top

    lastX = x;
    lastY = y;

    camera->ProcessMouseMovement(xoffset, yoffset);

    glutPostRedisplay();

  //this is the main thing that keeps it from leaving the screen
    if ( x < 100 || x > win_w - 100 ) {  //you can use values other than 100 for the screen edges if you like, kind of seems to depend on your mouse sensitivity for what ends up working best
        lastX = win_w/2;   //centers the last known position, this way there isn't an odd jump with your cam as it resets
        lastY = win_h/2;   
        glutWarpPointer(win_w/2, win_h/2);  //centers the cursor
    } else if (y < 100 || y > win_h - 100) {
        lastX = win_w/2;
        lastY = win_h/2;
        glutWarpPointer(win_w/2, win_h/2);
    } 
}
```

Hope this helps!